# oracle goldengate replication

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-19c, goldengate

Please I need help. Actually i am working on oracle 19c to perform a data base replication using the goldengate. I created two data bases (source and destination) the 3 processes (extract, pump and replicat) are running well, but when i insert datas in one data base for it to replicat in the other it's not replicating. Here is the link of the tutorial i used.

https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40madhukaudantha%2Fsetting-up-oracle-goldengate-12-9d9546a538d6&geid=NSTN&hl=en-US

this are the warning from the log file: 2021-08-30T05:52:38.284+0100  WARNING OGG-01877  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, MGR.prm:  Missing explicit accessrule for server collector.

2021-08-30T05:54:01.811+0100  WARNING OGG-01842  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, EXTRACT.prm:  CACHESIZE PER DYNAMIC DETERMINATION (7.66G) LESS THAN RECOMMENDED: 64G (64bit system)
vm found: 11.66G
Check swap space. Recommended swap/extract: 128G (64bit system).

2021-08-30T05:54:01.811+0100  INFO    OGG-01639  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, EXTRACT.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY:  ACTIVE: for object pool 1: p11804_extr.

2021-08-30T07:48:02.156+0100  WARNING OGG-00938  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, MGR.prm:  Manager is stopping at user request.

Comment: You should add details to your [original question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298802/oracle-datas-bases-replications-using-goldengate) if you think they are relevant, instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: This may be similar: https://mdinh.wordpress.com/2016/05/22/create-goldengate-12-2-manager/

Answer (score 1):

This seems that virtual memory configured less than recommended value. I suggest please increase the swap space and restart the gg porcesses.

For determine the swap space look into the below DOC ID : 1528945.1

Comment: thanks and this one WARNING OGG-02904

Comment: In what context you are getting this error OGG-02904? Doc ID 2019113.1